# Why is it bad to have a local functor?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010

For example, whats wrong with declaring the class doubler within the main function, if the predicate will only be used once?

```
#include <list>
#include <algorithm>
#define SIZE 10
int main()
{
    std::list<int> myList;
    for(int i=0; i<SIZE ;++i)
    {
        myList.push_back(i);
    }

    class doubler
    {
    public:
        doubler(){}
        int operator()(int a)
        {
            return a + a;
        }

    } pred;

    std::for_each(myList.begin(), myList.end(), pred);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The problem with this setup is that, at least in C++03, you cannot use a local functor as a template argument because it doesn't have external linkage.  This means that technically speaking, the above code isn't legal.  However, they're fixing this in C++0x since it's a pretty silly restriction, and since VS2010 has rudimentary C++0x support the above code is totally fine.

In short, the answer to your question is that there's nothing wrong with it if you're using C++0x-compliant compilers, but otherwise you should probably refrain from doing so to maximize cross-compiler compatibility.

Comment: well, if youre using VS2010 you can go for a lambda function directly. for_each(myList.begin(), myList.end(), [](int val){return val+val;});

Comment: vs2005 allows this as well, and on a sidenote, GCC gives a quite cryptic error msg, when the functor type is a template :/ (I ran into this when trying to compile some code which compiled totally fine with VS)

Comment: As an alternative, Boost's __LocalFunction__ or a similar local-functor idiom that delegates local functor calls to an object in outer scope can be used. Has the advantage of working exactly the same in C++03 and C++11.

Answer (score 5):

- It is illegal before C++0x
- In C++0x, there is a better solution (lambdas/closures)

So in either case you should use a different solution.