# Can you use a function local class as predicate to find_if?

Tags: c++

Is it possible to use a local class as a predicate to std::find_if?

```
#include <algorithm>

struct Cont
{
    char* foo()
    {

        struct Query
        {
            Query(unsigned column)
                : m_column(column) {}

            bool operator()(char c)
            {
                return ...;
            }

            unsigned m_column;
        };

        char str[] = "MY LONG LONG LONG LONG LONG SEARCH STRING";

        return std::find_if(str, str+45, Query(1));
    }
};

int main()
{
    Cont c;
    c.foo();

    return 0;
}
```

I get the following compiler error on gcc:

```
error: no matching function for call to 'find_if(char [52], char*, Cont::foo()::Query)'
```

Comment: Everyone can see your edit history, so there is no need to write an extra comment in your post saying what you edited.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In C++03 this is not allowed. ***Local***(not nested) classes cannot be template parameters. **In C++11 it is allowed.**

Some terminology tip:

A nested class is a class that is defined withing the scope of another class, e.g.

```
class A {class B{};};
```

A local class is class defined in function scope(as in your example)

Answer (score 1):

`Query` is a local class, not a nested class. This problem has been discussed [in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4582978/).